# Convert fields with empty or null values to JSON data on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, field

I have a table with several fields that I want to compile in just one json field. The problem is there several null and emtpy string values in those columns and y don't want to put them in the json, just store the relevant values. I want to do this with a minimum of queries as possible.

Here is my current approach:

```sql
    select
       json_remove(
         json_remove(json, json_search(json, 'one', 'null')),
         json_search(json, 'all', '')
       ) result
    from (
       select
              json_object(
                  'tag_1', coalesce(tag_1, 'null'),
                  'tag_2', coalesce(tag_2, 'null'),
                  'tag_3', coalesce(tag_3, 'null')
                ) json
       from leads
     ) l2;
```

But the problem is the json_search output is incompatible with the json_remove input. ¿Any ideas?

Here's some example data:

```
-------------------------
| tag_1 | tag_2 | tag_3 |
-------------------------
|   x   |       |  null |
|       |   y   |   z   |
-------------------------
```

And what I spect as a result:

```
--------------------------------
| result                       |
--------------------------------
| {'tag_1': 'x'}               |
| {'tag_2': 'y', 'tag_3': 'z'} |
--------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: Later I want too use the sentence to insert data in the json field... something like update leads set tagData = json_remove(...

Comment: Because SQL and JSON are both declarative languages, this combination which makes this question impossible to answer without knowing example data and expected results.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results...

Comment: I added the example data

Comment: Does it have to be dynamic or is the number of columns known and fixed?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eEW7DVPNMRCBRnBZ6mopNH/0) help some?

Comment: Thanks Raymond, but is not what I need, I need to put all the data in a just one Json by row... I'll extend the example.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks a lot for your comment it put me on track to discover the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the solution...

If somebody is interested in the solution....

With this data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `tag_1` VARCHAR(255),
  `tag_2` VARCHAR(255),
  `tag_3` VARCHAR(255),
  primary key (id)
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`tag_1`, `tag_2`, `tag_3`)
VALUES
  ('x', '', null),
  ('x','x', null),
  ('x', '', 'x'),
  ('x','x','x'),
  (null, null, 'x')
  ;
```

Here is the query:

```sql
select id, json_objectagg(field, val) as JSON  from (
  select id, 'tag_1' field, tag_1 val from t union
  select id, 'tag_2' field, tag_2 val from t union 
  select id, 'tag_3' field, tag_3 val from t
) sub where val is not null and val != ''
group by sub.id;
```

The subquery pivots the data to use `JSON_OBJECTAGG`

```
id  field   val
1   tag_1   x
2   tag_1   x
3   tag_1   x
4   tag_1   x
5   tag_1   null
1   tag_2   ''
2   tag_2   x
...
```

And then the grouping with json_objectagg does the trick!

```
| id  | JSON                                       |
| --- | ------------------------------------------ |
| 1   | {"tag_1": "x"}                             |
| 2   | {"tag_1": "x", "tag_2": "x"}               |
| 3   | {"tag_1": "x", "tag_3": "x"}               |
| 4   | {"tag_1": "x", "tag_2": "x", "tag_3": "x"} |
| 5   | {"tag_3": "x"}                             |
```

Here is the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aiW5QkNaP85mhShJ9vsEpK/0)

Thanks a lot to @Raimond Nijland for his comment, it put me on track! :)

Comment: Yes I'm interested. Thank you. It didn't help me directly, but i learned from it.